# Is it time for me to get serious about losing weight? (pics)

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat

Age:22
Height:5'7
Weight:230lbs
Waist:38 inches

[image]

Could be denial but I don't think its that concerning.

Comment: This question is too broad for a SE site, the answer basically comes down to your priorities.  Of course a fitness QA site will say to lose weight, but only you can say if it's "time to get serious"  If a doctor told you to lose weight, would that make it "time?"  When if you put on another 20 lbs? or 100?  What makes it "time" is when you decide you want to change (change your weight, habits, whatever) and make a plan to do so.  There are obese people who get told they _have_ to lose weight or die, and they decide they care more about enjoying good food than being healthy.  Different strokes.

Comment: Here's my suggestion: find *(or buy)* a full length mirror and periodically, check yourself naked in the mirror while asking yourself, **"Is this the best I can make of my body?"** ***If you're honest with your assessment,*** you'll find the courage and determination to do the proper thing. If you're not honest with yourself, you probably don't need to do anything because you won't achieve much without an honest assessment of yourself :).

Comment: On the honest assesment front, are you sure about the waist, the NIH / US military state the waist, on males, should be measured at the Umbilicus (Navel). Anyway if you're serious about losing weight I'd go further, than @Kneel-Before-ZOD, and suggest you start using one or more of the app's / sites such as MyFitnessPal, MapMyFitness...., and make sure your vitals and workouts are visible to all your Facebook / Google+ friends. You'll be encouraged one way or the other to keep going (lose weight, improve times, increase distances....).

Comment: @Frisbee I understand I'm overweight but obese seems a bit hyperbolic.

Comment: Per the medical definition you are obese.  http://www.cdc.gov/obesity/adult/defining.html  Your BMI is 35.   For your height even 191 is obese.

Comment: @Livingtitan - As Frisbee says, you are obese, and teetering near the edges of being morbidly obese. "Could be" denial, it IS denial. Additionally, you are asking for digestive problems if you keep wearing pants with waistbands that tight. Just because you can get the buttons in, doesn't mean it's actually fitting. (If your pants are what you are basing your "38 waist" on).

Comment: @Frisbee well that sucks.

Comment: @Livintitan, hopefully this is your wake up call.   You can get help here along the way as you have more questions.  Also, the NIH has some info to help you get started with a [weight loss plan](http://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/health-topics/weight-control/choosing-safe-successful-weight-loss-program/Pages/choosing-safe-successful-weight-loss-program.aspx).

Comment: I would suggest medical attention after that sick burn by @BruceDoh

Answer (score 10):

While I assume this question will be closed - it might fall outside the scope of this StackExchange - I'd still like to answer.

Yes. It is absolutely time to lose some weight. Keep in mind, **I do not judge you**.

**Fat problems or heart problems?**

The reason I say yes, is because there is quite a bit of excess fat there. While that, in and of itself, isn't the biggest of deals, it does tell me something about your other habits.

First and foremost, I see signs of bad dietary habits. Little regard for nutrition, and more regard for taste, maybe? Gaining fat isn't the only symptom. But excessive fat gain tells the tale of bad diet, which again is known to cause a bunch of other problems. Not least of which is heart disease. So while you may disregard the fat as OK, think of your heart.

You don't need to diet just to lose fat. Change your diet for the sake of your heart, and the fat will naturally subside.

**Posture**

Additionally, there is the issue of posture. Might be you have a very seated lifestyle. Desk job and desk hobbies maybe?

One very good way to combat this is to get a desk which can be raised/lowered on demand. I have one both at work and at home, and spend around 2 hours total standing, when I would normally have been sitting. This has done wonders for my back, as I was also bothered by poor posture. All that slouching is no good.

**So yes**

Again, while the fat itself is OK, it tells a tale. You don't need to be motivated to look better. Motivate yourself to improving your health. The body will look better as a result.

Answer (score 3):

You’re opening yourself up to lots of opinions.  But, one of the indicators that could impress on you to make a change is your [BMI](http://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/adult_bmi/english_bmi_calculator/bmi_calculator.html).  There are others, but, a BMI of **36** suggests obesity and the possibility of an onset of a host of medical problems.  I would suggest you discuss your weight with your personal physician and get a complete medical check up to rule out any health concerns before they become chronic.

Comment: BMI is not an accurate and should not be used to guage the "fatness" of people. http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=106268439

Comment: My answer uses BMI as an indicator of potential health risks and a suggestion of obesity, not, a measure of "fatness".

Comment: But you did go there and plug in his measurements before you commented, correct?

Comment: Anyone trying to argue that he *doesn't * need to lose fat is kidding themselves.

Comment: Waist (at Navel) to height or hip (largest buttock circumference) ratios have been shown to be a more accurate indicator of potential health problems. As BMI fails for those with more muscle than fat (body builders, pro athletes...) and for amputees, but in this case I wouldn't discount the: WHO, NIH, NICE .... BMI based classification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is time to get serious about creating and living a healthy lifestyle.
The way you look is the least concern of excess weight.

> [Your risk for diseases](http://www.howtogetbackinshape.com/Obesity.html#Obesity-Health-Risks) such as diabetes, hypertension and cardiovascular disease, cancer, osteoarthritis, liver disease, reproductive problems, metabolic syndrome and sleep apnea increases as your BMI increases.

Your [BMI at 36](http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/educational/lose_wt/BMI/bmicalc.htm) places you in the Class 2 classification of obesity.

Change your unhealthy habits to healthy habits such as:

- Eat nutritious food in healthy proportions
- Increase your daily activity - daily exercise such as walking, cycling, swimming etc. [Interrupt sitting](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24937/what-happens-to-people-who-are-sitting-8-10h-per-day/24941#24941) frequently.
- Socialize with active people - find an active sport that you enjoy
- Learn to fully relax to release the stresses of the day.

Are you in denial?  Yes, in my opinion, you are. Given that, "More than two-thirds (68.8 percent) of adults are considered to be overweight or obese." [according to NIH](http://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/health-statistics/Pages/overweight-obesity-statistics.aspx), you may be comparing yourself with similarly overweight people.

Step one is to decide that you want to change.  Here are some additional suggestions for getting started on a new plan: [Starting Exercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/how-to-get-started-with-exercising-without-any-previous-experience/3122#3122),  [Types of Exercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12860/beginner-in-physical-fitness-need-tips-and-advices/12864#12864)

Comment: BMI is not an accurate and should not be used to guage the "fatness" of people. http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=106268439

Comment: @Hituptony Look at the pics.  Is the BMI in spec?

Comment: @Hituptony, I am aware of the [pluses and minuses of BMI](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10001/how-can-you-do-a-bmi-test/10014#10014).  However, the photos posted seem to confirm that in this case there is a correlation between the BMI value and "fatness."  I read the article that you linked too, but I didn't find reference links  to back up conclusion such as, "mathematical snake oil" and "That's total nonsense."

Comment: Is the BMI in spec? It's an outdated measurement so I don't use it...it's not always accurate. Would you drink water if it wasn't clean, but it was clean enough, based on a chart that's been proven to be not true in all cases? What other reasoning do you have? Visceral fat deposits around stomach? OP is asking for observational analysis not the BMI

Comment: Falling back on the BMI because it correlates to this case is only somewhat relevant,it doesn't always correlate so it's therefore an inaccurate measuring tool. What other supporting evidence do you have that he needs to lose weight? Your answer is overall very clear and accurate but what brought you to it? Just the BMI or could you tell visually before you plugged his measurements in?

Comment: @Hituptony, the point is that my answer is "clear and accurate" and will be of benefit to Livingtitan should he follow the links and recommendations.  If you want or need understanding of the proper use and application of BMI, I refer you to the [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/obesity/downloads/BMIforPactitioners.pdf), [WHO](http://apps.who.int/bmi/index.jsp?introPage=intro_3.html),  and [NIH](http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/educational/lose_wt/risk.htm).  Any further questions or comments should probably be moved to chat.